# how to load chart values from json url and display in mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to load data from json url and pass values to mpandroidchart lib.or can you suggest when chart lib is easy to load json data and draw charts

Comment: you need to start from here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use library Volley to parser JSON
then load data to ArrayList in MPAndroidChart